# IE showing image (png) larger than actual size. Firefox displays it correctly

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I have png images showing larger than their real dimensions in IE8. the img tag doesn't have width & height attributes. The images look fine in Firefox. Is this an issue with IE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try pressing CTRL 0

Comment: @Richard it resets the zoom level to "normal"

Comment: However, there is another possibility:  .pngs display much larger, in KB when saved, in IE11 than in Firefox or Chrome - which caused us much confusion.  Ref. https://superuser.com/questions/579216/why-does-this-png-image-display-differently-in-chrome-firefox-than-in-safari-a  for more details.  Apparently something to do with whether and how browser apply "gamma correction".

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```
img { -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; }
```

Sorry should have been a comment I guess...

I found this solution on the css tricks website, It has to do with the way IE renders/re-sizes images which apparently is different from other browsers.

I had the same problem and in-fact this ended up NOT working, but I thought it might be worth a try because the post described the same problem.

I ended up solving it by changing the image style from width:100%; to width:50%; so that it would work on all browsers. Maybe that could work for you too.

Basically it ended up being smaller in Chrome/Firefox and normal size in IE. Instead of normal size in Chrome/Firefox and way too big in IE.

But one thing is for sure, *YES this is a problem with IE*.

Also I noticed the TOR browser has the same exact problem.